# Page loads without content when accessed directly

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, themes, nimble

so we're having a very strange problem here. Whenever we try to open one of our blog entries directly by typing its URL into the browser, it doesn't load correctly (without any text). However, when we try to access it over a link on another page, it works just fine.

Even more strange: When we see the broken page and click Inspect Element, the missing content appears. This might be because the site is being reloaded when you click that.

The problem only exists in Chrome and only on this website:

Direct URL: http://www.myfeelix.de/immobilienkauf-behalten-sie-den-ueberblick-beim-papierkram/
(try copying this manually into the browser and you'll see what I mean)

Accessing it from this website works (first blog entry up top): http://www.myfeelix.de/category/feelix-experten-blog/
Anyone got any ideas?

UPDATE: The problem disappears when we disable Google Fonts. Any more ideas why this is causing a problem?

Comment: It works fine when I try it. Perhaps a cache problem?

Comment: We disabled Google Fonts that's why it works now. FYI it seems to be a general problem since the last Chrome update. We are currently waiting for the next update. Just in case other ppl experience the same problem.